# Is there a way to scale a site to fit all screens and still show all content without a scrollbar?

Tags: html, css, scale, viewport

My website www.skultuur.com looks awesome on my 27" iMac and mobile devices, but when I use smaller laptop screens the content zooms in dramatically forcing a scroll bar. Is there a way to scale the site to fit all screens and still show all content without a scrollbar?

Its been months and i haven't found any working code

image of what I'm talking about:

[image]

it doesn't have to have that much blank space underneath just has to fit all content; images, links, footer etc. without any scrolling.

Answer (score 2):

Use **media queries**. You can set specific css for different width etc.. This will make your site responsive.

We can help you in specific parts alone. You have to learn it and use it in your website.

Read about it at http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/